# how to change the marked area of ai file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an AI file, which contains a logo, but if I want to convert the file into pdf format, it selects only a part of the logo (in the middle of the logo graphics there is a white box), what do I have to do to get the whole logo into the "white box", so when I save it as a pdf file the whole logo would get saved not only a small part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the artboard size.

Click on Document Setup
[image]

click on edit artboards
[image]

Then click and drag the handles to make your art board big enough so that your logo sits on the artboard completely.
[image]

Now, when you safe your logo, it should print fine.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Choose `Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds`, then save the file.